# Can I use Fabric React in SharePoint 2013 without SPFX?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to use Fabric React JS in SharePoint 2013 Environment without SPFx. Is it Possible to use and deploy?

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { CommandBar, ICommandBarProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar';
import { CommandBarButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

export class CommandBarButtonAsExample extends React.Component<ICommandBarProps, {}> {

  constructor(props: ICommandBarProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {

    const customButton = (props: IButtonProps) => {
      const buttonOnMouseEnter = () => console.log(`${props.text} hovered`);
      return (
        <CommandBarButton
          onMouseEnter={ buttonOnMouseEnter }
          { ...props }
          styles={ {
            ...props.styles,
            icon: { color: 'red' }
          } }
        />
      );
    };

    const { items, overflowItems, farItems } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <CommandBar
          buttonAs={ customButton }
          items={ items }
          overflowItems={ overflowItems }
          farItems={ farItems }
          ariaLabel={ 'Use left and right arrow keys to navigate between commands' }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/commandbar

Can I use Fabric React in our SP 2013 Environment?

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is **YES,** we can use Office UI fabric without SPFX. Fabric UI is just like a 3rd party library.
You can create a simple React project and install the Office Fabric UI dependencies.

```
npm i --save office-ui-fabric-react react react-dom redux redux-thunk react-redux
```

Do check out this blog Using [Office Fabric UI](http://dattabase.com/office-fabric-ui-reactredux-part-3-5/).
Also, have a look onto the [Part1](http://dattabase.com/office-fabric-ui-reactredux-part-1-5/) for setting up the project

**EDIT 1:**
There is a ***framework-independent*** Fabric UI components which you can directly consume by using CDNs. I have created a sample web part page and added a Script Editor web part to it. And this works like charm.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="ms-font-su ms-fontColor-themePrimary">I am Blue !</span><br/>
<button class="ms-Button">
  <span class="ms-Button-label">Click Me</span>
</button>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ButtonComponent = document.querySelector(".ms-Button");
new fabric["Button"](ButtonComponent, function() {
  alert("I am Clicked");
});
</script>
</html>
```

ScreenShot : 
[image]

Comment: Here, Installing Redux is optioal

Comment: Thanks. But how we can use Fabric React as Client Side App Part? I don't want to use Provider Hosted App/SharePoint Hosted App. Do you have any deployment steps?

Comment: Hi, Let me clarify one thing here, If you are creating a client-side web part where you are using React and other JS framework eventually you will end up in SP compatible App/solution. So, SPFX is just one point collection of all dependencies related to SP client side solution Project. Now, If we talk about deployment, it is same like using a task runner like gulp to do the job like Build, Package, Uploading the Solution then Installing the App.   Refer : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page

Comment: Thanks for response. I have edited question. Now, is it possible to use Fabric React in our SP 2013 Environment? If Yes, without any APP Solution i.e. SharePoint Hosted/Provider Hosted App is it possible?

Comment: Hi Prashant, If you are not using any SP solution /app then You will be left with limited options to put your scripts into SharePoint by using Script Editor/Client Editor web parts. And these built-in webparts works only in Classic Mode. I am not sure what exactly is you are trying to achieve but I would recommend you to inject your custom scripts/solutions using App model only. Anyway, I have updated my Answer pls do check.

Comment: @DvG,I think there is little bit confusion here. I think "Office Fabric UI" and "Office UI Fabric React" both are different concepts. And Prashant is trying to ask if we can use "Office UI Fabric React" technology in content editor web part and without  SPFx - client side web parts or not?

Comment: @Dikesh.. Thanks for pointing out. I believe Fabric UI react also we can do. And since React will use its own react-project template. Same is mentioned under Part1 Link of my answer............ Any other thought on this will be appreciated

Comment: After button click page is getting refreshed, any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

it may work on a **classic** page but as far as i know, the only way to use Fabric UI React in a **modern** page is within an SPFX web part / app customizer - and a custom SPFX webpart can be deployed in SP2016 but not in SP2013

the suggested solution is based on Fabric UI JS which is a separate framework, that is designed for non-SharePoint O365 addons

from my own experience it conflicts with SharePoint modern experience styling (because it overrides styles)

also some sources recommend the React framework over the JS version, more information can be found here
http://andrewconnell.com/blog/avoid-the-office-ui-fabric-javascript-package

Comment: it seems the styling issues were reported by others, a workaround that is suggested is to download the css (and js) files and rename all classes from prefix ms- into something else, you end up then with a custom solution that mimics the O365 modern experience https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/434